# Передача в Callback конкретного наследника

Tags: java, generics

Мне нужно в метод класса передать `Consumer`, но так, чтобы аргументом этого `Consumer` был конкретный экземпляр этого класса или его наследника. Что-то типа такого

```
class A {
    <T extends A> void test(Consumer<T> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int getVal() {
        return 0;
    }
}
class C {
    void consume(B data) {
        System.out.println(data.getVal());
    }
    
    void test() {
        B data = new B();
        data.test(this::consume);
    }
}
```

сейчас на строке

```
consumer.accept(this);
```

ошибка

> accept(T) in Consumer cannot be applied to A

можно поставить явный каст

```
consumer.accept((T)this);
```

тогда ошибка заменяется на warning

> Unchecked cast 'A' to 'T'

пытался изобразить что-то типа наследования

```
class A {
    void test(Consumer<A> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void test(Consumer<B> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
    }
    
    int getVal() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> name clash: test(Consumer) in B and test(Consumer) in A have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

А как сделать правильно?

Comment: `Unchecked cast 'A' to 'T'` - не ошибка, а предупреждение.

Comment: А зачем оверрайть метод в классе `B`? разве если использовать родительский метод (во втором варианте) это не будет тем что Вам нужно?

Comment: @Tsyklop я так и написал

Comment: @AlexeyR. мне нужно вызвать коллбек в родительском классе, а в самом коллбеке получить доступ к методам дочернего. А без оверрайда мне нужно будет кастовать параметр в самом коллбеке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в оригинальном варианте возникает, так как тип `Т` с ограничением `T extends A` можно использовать в любом контексте, где можно использовать `А`, т.е. проще говоря можно безопасно привести к `A`, а вот наоборот - нельзя.

Именно такое приведение `A` к `T` нужно, чтоб использовать `A` (это есть тип `this`) в выражении `consumer.accept(this)`.

Ведь если бы это допустил компилятор без явного приведения, то можно было бы написать:

```
class C extends A {
  void consume(C data) {
  }
  
  void test() {
      B data = new B();
      data.test(this::consume);
  }
}
```

С очевидной проблемой, что `C::consume` получает на вход объект типа `B`.

С явным приведением так тоже можно написать, но предупреждение компилятора как раз и говорит, что код не является типо безопасным и может бросить `ClassCastException` во время  выполнения.

Что касается того, как правильно исправить, то это зависит от некоторых условий, которые явно не определены в вопросе, очевидно, в связи з попыткой сделать минимальный пример.

Если я правильно предполагаю, что `test` реализует шаблонный метод, то наиболее универсальным видится вариант явной передачи наследника:

```
class A {
  static <T extends A> void test(T t, Consumer<T> consumer) {
      consumer.accept(t);
  }
}

...
  void test() {
      B data = new B();
      A.test(data, this::consume);
  }
```

В этом случае сохраняется возможность вызова методов из наследника и private методов из A (c явным приведением):

```
class A {
  static <T extends A> void test(T t, Consumer<T> consumer) {
      consumer.accept(t);
      t.virtual();
      ((A)t).private_method(); 
  }

  protected void virtual() {
  }

  private void private_method() {
  }
}

class B extends A {
  int getVal() {
      return 0;
  }
  
  protected void virtual() {
  }
}
```

Альтернативный вариант - это добавить в базовый класс информацию о типе наследника:

```
abstract class A<T> {
  void test(Consumer<T> consumer) {
      consumer.accept(getThis());
  }

  protected abstract T getThis();
}

class B extends A<B> {
  int getVal() {
      return 0;
  }

  @Override
  protected B getThis() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. До статического метода я не додумался.

Comment: А исходная задача: запустить асинхронную процедуру, а потом получить в `onComplete()` объект именно того класса, откуда запустили